# Create array of class in that class

Tags: c++, class, incomplete-type

I'm trying to add a QuadTree in c++.  I have this code so far:

```
class QuadTree {
private:
    AABB bounds;

    QuadTree children[]; // this line
public:
    QuadTree(AABB bounds) : bounds(bounds) {

    }
};
```

But I get an error "Error: incomplete type is not allowed".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I answered [in About C++ classes with self reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22508215/1708801) classes are not allowed to contain non-static members of themselves. You can use references or pointers though. A class is not complete until the closing `}` which explains the error message w/ the exception of within class methods.

Comment: afaik most used solution is to use pointers, just remember about providing valid dtor and ctors if you allocate dynamic memory

Comment: The flexible array would be an error in itself.

Comment: not true, it compiles just fine

Comment: @lizusek Probably on a non-compliant compiler. C++ doesn't allow incomplete types as members or flexible arrays.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.7, yes

Comment: @lizusek Here's a run with gcc 4.8: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a06113aec54248c3. I get similar results with clang 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard 9.2.4 says:

> Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. In
>   particular, a class C shall not contain a non-static member of class
>   C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C.

This means you cannot declare

```
class A {
    public:
        A a;  // error: field ‘a’ has incomplete type
};
```

But you can:

```
class A {
    public:
        A* a;
};
```

---

Solution:

```
class QuadTree {
private:
    AABB bounds;
    QuadTree* children;
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't declare an array without size. Your error is exactly telling it;)

Secondly, you're not allowed to create an object of the same class in the class of object.

Only what can you do is to make reference or pointer in this class to an object of the same class.

So change this:

```
QuadTree children[]; // this line
```

to this:

```
QuadTree **children; // this line
```

Comment: *First of all you can'd declare an array without size.* Actually, you can.

Comment: @faranwath not in any standard thus far.  Some compiler extensions allow it though.

Comment: @SamCristall I tried both GCC and Clang with the `-std=c++11` option. They both accept the code.

Comment: @faranwath They both have dynarray extensions.

Comment: so it is not an error itself

Comment: @faranwath The code doesn not compile on gcc 4.8.2 with reasonable flags. Because it is not standards compliant C++.

Comment: @SamCristall Wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @juanchopanza I wasn't compiling **that** code, but one of my own with an `int a[];` member.

Comment: @faranwath That shouldn't compile either.

Comment: @juanchopanza Guilty as charged, but it kinda does. Don't kill the messenger.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, you cannot create a non-static instance of the same class inside of itself. However, no answers have why this is true. Take this code for example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private: std::string s;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
}
```

When we declare `MyClass c` we are also initializing it by calling its default constructor. When we do this, it has to allocate (and initialize) the memory for each of the members of `MyClass` so it also calls `std::string` constructor. Now if instead of this, `MyClass` was defined as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
     // note: not legal.
    private: MyClass c;
}
```

then the `MyClass` constructor would call the `MyClass` constructor would call the `MyClass` constructor ...

We would have infinite recursion and run out of memory. Now when we define `MyClass` as such:

```
class MyClass
{
    private: MyClass* c;
}
```

When we create a `MyClass`, we only have to allocate the memory for the pointer and everything would be fine. However this snippet would cause the same problem during runtime, but it would be perfectly legal code.

```
class MyClass
{

    private: MyClass* c;
    public: MyClass(){ c = new MyClass(); }
}
```